# Cannot publish from InfoPath, even if I start fresh from SharePoint and don't change anything

Tags: infopath, publishing

**This is the error message I am getting when I try to "Quick Publish":**

> The SOAP response indicates that an error occurred on the server:
>   Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The issue I am having is very similar to the one listed and solved [here](https://kerdirks.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/infopath-2010-form-soap-response-error-on-server/), but I tried all of his steps listed for solving the problem (the "Troubleshooting" section), and it did not fix my problem. In fact, there were not even any errors listed in the Design Checker.

**Here are the things I have tried so far:**

1. The steps listed in the linked-to article. *Result: no change.*
2. I tried comparing all list data types and parameters to make sure the settings in InfoPath and SharePoint match. *Result: everything matches and is compatible.*
3. I tried re-downloading the already published form, then publishing it again without making any changes, to see if I could start fresh. *Result: I get the same error message.*

If you need any other data to help me identify and fix the issue, please let me know. I am new to SharePoint/InfoPath, so I'm not sure what other data I should be providing here. **Please help!**

Comment: After not getting any answers here, and spending a lot of time fiddling with the settings in SharePoint (to no avail), I eventually decided to rebuild the form. I reset the form (in SharePoint) to the default form, checking the box to delete InfoPath forms stored on the server, and then went to the list and clicked on "Customize in InfoPath" to rebuild the form. It works now, but if anyone knows a way to fix the problem without rebuilding, for future reference, please still write an answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I was helpless. I found a quick way to fix it without recreating the form from scratch.

1. Go to List Setting --> Form Setting
2. Select "Use the default sharepoint form" --> Apply the change
3. Go to Form setting again and Click on "Delete the custom form"
4. Open that Form from your Infopath local copy and Publish it again
   This will re connect all fields and upload the form in to Sharepoint with a new data connection which is error free.

Mine worked! Hope this will work for you
Cheers!